# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: jquery

I know there are similar questions but nothing seems too work for my current issue. I have a simple audio player with progress bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".audio-clip .volume").on("input", function() {
    var audio = $(this)
      .closest("div")
      .find("audio")[0];
    audio.volume = this.value;
  });

  $(".audio-clip .position").on("input", function() {
    var audio = $(this)
      .closest("div")
      .find("audio")[0];
    audio.currentTime = (audio.duration / 100) * this.value;
  });

  $("audio").on("timeupdate", function() {
    var pc = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
    $(this)
      .closest("div")
      .find(".position")
      .val(pc);
  });
```

and in the html

```
   <label>
    Position:
    <input type="range" class="position" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />

    <progress class="nes-progress is-pattern position" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </label>
```

all works as expected but in the JS console I see

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite
```

Comment: I'll bet `audio.duration` is `0`, causing a division by 0.

Comment: What does `console.log(pc)` show?

Comment: @Barmar actually the controller works fine, the audio files loaded have a duration and all is functional but I get this error for every loaded file :(

Comment: Answer my question, what's the value of `pc` when this happens?

Comment: You forgot to set `audio` in the last function.

Comment: @barmar console.log(pc) shows 0.045581364959371436
index.js:139 0.16307945099086107
index.js:139 0.280795359557636
index.js:102 tick
index.js:139 0.39744991253131445
index.js:139 0.514844027115076
index.js:139 0.6345791458793556
index.js:139 0.7513607227936971
index.js:102 tick

Comment: @Barmar do you mean:   $("audio").on("timeupdate", function() {
    var audio = $(this);
    var pc = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
    console.log(pc);  -- if I do that I get the sam error and console.log returns NaN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201976/discussion-between-devnull-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `pc` is a valid number before trying to use it to set the value.

```
  $("audio").on("timeupdate", function() {
    var pc = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
    if (isNaN(pc)) {
      return;
    }
    $(this)
      .closest("div")
      .find(".position")
      .val(pc);
  });
```